# Create Key Value pairs from dynamic column count in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a google sheet that has a 1 column with a "key" of data and then a horizontal column dynamically filled data,  I am trying to create a single long "key value" pair of data that fills in the cells,  these are strings so some number based hacks do not work :/

| Num | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Key1 | v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | key2 | va1 | va2 | va3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | key3 | vb1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | key3 | vc1 | vc2 | vc3 | vc4 | vc5 | vc6 | vc7 | vc8 | vc9 |

My goals is to turn it into 2 columns that are purely key value

| Num | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Key1 | v1 |
| 2 | Key1 | v2 |
| 3 | Key1 | v3 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 10 | Key3 | vc1 |
| 11 | Key3 | vc2 |

I have tried various "unpivot" solutions but they tend to require static column counts instead of the dynamic column counts that I will have instead

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve your showing input and output situation using Google Apps Script.
- In your showing output table, it seems that row 10 is `Key3,vc1`. But, from your sample input table, I guessed that row 10 might be `key3,vc2`.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and set your sheet name and save the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const values = range.getValues().flatMap(([h, ...v]) => v.filter(String).map(e => [h, e]));
  range.clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

This script overwritten the existing cells. But, for example, if you want to put the result values from row 10, please replace the last 2 lines in the above script as follows.

```
sheet.getRange(10, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

### Added:

About your following reply,

> is there a reason why you made the app script this way as opposed to a function that can be called within the sheet? it seems like every time I make a change to the base sheet I have to go over to app script and run it for the change to replicate Why not make the function take in a range input? (I know very little about app script or its limitations / abilities)

From `google-apps-script` of your tags, I understood that you wanted to achieve your goal by Google Apps Script. And, when Google Apps Script is used, I thought that you might have wanted to overwrite the existing cells with new values. So, I proposed the above script. This is the reason for `is there a reason why you made the app script this way as opposed to a function that can be called within the sheet?`.

If your actual expected result was `a function that can be called within the sheet`, how about the above script as a custom function as follows?

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script.

```js
const SAMPLE = v => v.flatMap(([h, ...v]) => v.filter(String).map(e => [h, e]));
```

When you use this script as a custom function, please put `=SAMPLE(A1:J4)` into a cell. By this, the result value is returned.

Comment: is there a reason why you made the app script this way as opposed to a function that can be called within the sheet?

it seems like every time I make a change to the base sheet I have to go over to app script and run it for the change to replicate

Why not make the function take in a range input?  (I know very little about app script or its limitations / abilities)

Comment: @dtracers Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I didn't notice that you wanted to use Google Apps Script as a custom function. So, I added a script for it. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your actual expected result again, I apologize again. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Thanks!!! That was really helpful to learn.  (Your English is great!)

Comment: @dtracers About `Thanks!!! That was really helpful to learn. (Your English is great!)`, welcome and thank you! Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer